# Why didn't I receive a half bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I answered this question:

[configure-secured-websockets-using-apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144426/configure-secured-websockets-using-apache-httpd-2-4-6-and-tomcat-8/31276659#31276659)

It's honestly not one of my best, and I am not really concerned whether or not I get the rep from it, I just want to understand the rules.

It is my understanding that the rules are that if the grace period ends and the bounty has not been awarded by the question owner, the answer that has received the highest number of up votes (with a minimum of 2) will receive half the bounty.

If this is the case, shouldn't I have received half the bounty for this answer?

---

Screenshot:

[image: notice]

Hovering over "yesterday" shows

> started at 2015-07-02 23:57:25Z
>    ended at 2015-07-09 23:57:25Z

(As of 2015-07-11 00:40:00Z)

Comment: According [to here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147491/244519) wait 1-2 hours for script to run.

Comment: At the very least, there is a punctuation bug there. Missing a giant dot at the end of sentence.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The chronology of events, in UTC time (see [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31144426/revisions)):

1. Bounty started at 2015-07-02 23:57:25
2. Bounty period ended at 2015-07-09 23:57:25Z
3. 24-hour grace period ended at 2015-07-10 23:57:25Z
4. Bounty awarded at 2015-07-11 01:57:35Z

According to [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118070/259867), bounty-awarding script runs once an hour, which is why the award is not immediate.

Additionally, it appears that the system  gives a last-chance 1 hour postponement prior to award, apart from the irregularity due to scheduling. Indeed, all automatic awards I've looked at happened 60-120 minutes after the end of the grace period:

- [70 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24527488/revisions)
- [76 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30303414/revisions)
- [101 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25689933/revisions)
- [119 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24256686/revisions)